# Input string was not in a correct format in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am facing the error "Input string was not in a correct format." while using the variable in for loop.

```
$totalrows=$filepath |% {$n = $_; $c = 0; Get-Content -Path $_ -ReadCount 1000 |% { $c += $_.Count }; "$n; $c"}
echo $totalrows
```

Output is `8` and it is correct.

Used this variable in for loop:

```
For ($i = 0; $i -lt $totalrows; $i++) {
    Write-host $i 
}
```

but i get the error :

```
8" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

So, I looked into SO for same questions so i found to typecast into integer:

```
$totalrows=$filepath |% {$n = $_; $c = 0; Get-Content -Path $_ -ReadCount 1000 |% { $c += $_.Count }; "$n; $c"}
$totalrowscast=[int]$totalrows
echo $totalrowscast

For ($i = 0; $i -lt $totalrowscast; $i++) {
    Write-host $i 
}
```

But still I am facing the same error.

Comment: Put a `write-host $totalrows.gettype()` to see what type you are getting.

Comment: System.String its printing

Comment: What do you expect? The last item on pipeline _is_ a string: `"$n; $c"` that will give you a string that contains two things separated with a semicolon.

Comment: i expect the variable $totalrows to be integer.

Comment: Then just output `$c`, not `"$n; $c"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outputting a single string containing both the *path* AND the row count, eg. `"path; 8"`, which can't be converted to a numerical type, hence the error.

You don't need to manually count each chunk read by `Get-Content` - the cmdlet already adds a line number to each string it outputs, so you can simply discard everything but the *last* line and its line number will be the line count (excluding any trailing newline):

```
$totalrows = Get-Content $filepath |Select -Last 1 -ExpandProperty ReadCount
```

The `ReadCount` property is already an `[int]`, so everything will start working expected, including `$i -lt $totalrows`